# Knex seed and primary key sequence

Tags: postgresql, migration, knex.js, seeding

I using knex.js for seedings and migrations. With code similar to following.

```
exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  knex.schema.table('users', function(table) {
    table.dropColumn('fullname')
  })
}


exports.seed = function(knex, Promise) {
  // Deletes ALL existing entries
  return knex('users').del()
  .then(function () {
    // Inserts seed entries
    return knex('users').insert([
      {
        id: 1,
        email: 'nigel@email.com',
        password: 'dorwssap'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        email: 'nakaz@email.com',
        password: 'password1'
      },
      {
        id: 3
        email: 'jaywon@email.com',
        password: 'password123'
      }
    ]);
  });
};
```

But when I trying to insert new data into the table - autoincrement doesn't work until I update sequence manually. How could I fix this issue?

Comment: you probably need to define the table with a `serial` data type in Postgres, not knex

Comment: @richyen Using specificType(name, "serial") doesn't help. 
I trying to find a way to peform
ALTER SEQUENCE product_id_seq RESTART WITH 1453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When data is inserted with explicit `id` given, postgresql does not read the value from id_sequence thus, the sequence will not be incremented on every insert.

You need to create data without giving ids explicitly or otherwise you need to update each table's id sequence to correct values after creating the initial data.